# Maintaining local pivot point when importing FBX to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: export, unreal-engine

Hi this is my first time making my own digital asset for a game and I'm running into some oddities.

So far:

1. I have a single .blend file which has meshes for my missile turret. My turret has three parts, a base, a rack that spins on top of the base, and a missile launcher itself which pitches up and own in the rack.
2. Since I needed these three parts separate when exporting while maintaining their relatives positions, I grouped them into three groups and used Batch(Groups) setting on FBX export. This produced three FBX files.
3. Then I imported them into UE4 and everything seemed to work fine. When I make a blueprint object and add three static meshes, They maintain their local positions without additional tweaking. I made a yaw script so that only the base stays still but the rack and missile launcher which is child of rack rotates to face the desired target.
4. The missile launcher needs to pitch by rotating on its own pivot(centre of its mass) to face targets with differing altitudes. When I use pitch, my missile launcher needs to rotate on it's own local pivot, ie) center of it's mass/vertices. However it started to rotate using pivot (0,0,0) for some reason.
5. I read this post: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/23349/how-to-permanently-change-the-pivot-of-a-static-me.html, so I went back to the .blend file and changed the local pivot of missile launcher by moving the cursor to the center of the missile launcher and setting pivot option to cursor.
6. It didn't work and I decided to edit the individual .FBX file. However, UE4 seems deadsat on keeping the pivot on (0,0,0) and only way to change the pivot point is to align each meshes's desired pivot to (0,0,0) which I do not want to do as it does not preserve the location of each meshes relative to each other.

Am I supposed to rig the turret with bones and then import it as a single item? I didn't want to do that as it seemed unnecessary with no complex animations, just yaw and pitch is all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some infos about importing from Blender to Unreal Engine 4 from this page: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Static_Mesh_from_Blender#Pivot_Points

As you can read, you should place the origin where you want your pivot point to be. For example, for a basic hinged door, you should do [image: something like this].

I'm not sure if you said you did not want to do something like this, but it seems like there's no way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I realized that most other game engines do the same as well, pivot at the origin. Instead of importing separate .fbx, I just made a simple armature for the turret and imported it as a skeletal mesh in UE4.